# How to create access with write permission only on Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I read the manual but I'm not understand how to create this, it's not similar to AWS. I want to send backups from my Instance to GCS using gsutil command line. But I don't want to use my admin credentials in the instance, it's not secure, I want to create another user, with a single permission to write files in GCS, not delete, list, whatever. How can I make this on Google Console? IAM tells me to create a Google account, this is really necessary for this simple task?

Comment: In the console, you can create a service account (not the same as the usual Google account) representing your "other user."  Creating service accounts is pretty easy: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts

Comment: I tried that first and didn't worked, but now I got it. But I authenticated using JSON file and "gsutil cp" needs permission to "create" and "list" objects to work. But listing objects offers to a hacker overwriting all the files in my bucket. Can I make cp works without list permission?

Comment: gsutil cp uses list permission to figure out whether the destination is considered a bucket subdirectory, which in turn helps for determining the naming of the destination objects.  So gsutil cp to the root-level of the bucket will work without list permission, but copying outside of the root-level requires list permission.  Granting list permission doesn't affect overwriting files in the bucket; your account still won't have delete permission so you are safe from overwrites.  Does that work for your use case?

Comment: The root-level requires list permission too, i'm sending to gs://bucket/file.tar and it's requiring me the list action. With a permission to list the bucket the hacker can list all the files inside it, see all the backups and create fake files with the same name of it one, then run the cp command to send those files to overwrite the entire bucket. For now I'm using GCS to store the backups, it's working, but i'll have to check this situation in the near future.

Comment: By "root level" I meant "cp file.tar gs://bucket".  As for the scenario you described, the overwrites would fail because the account does not have permission to overwrite objects.  Overwrite requires storage.objects.delete which is not included in the object-creator or viewer roles.  An unauthorized user would need to predict your future object names to disrupt your pipeline.  Note that if an unauthorized user has write access to your bucket you have major problems regardless because that user can upload arbitrary amounts of data to the bucket and cause a large bill for you.

Comment: Thanks @TravisHobrla! You're rgith about the large bill and there is nothing I can do about it, there is no option to limit the size of the bucket, just alerts about high cost.

Do you know how would I enable an instance in the console to use the Storage, enable Storage write access to the default service account to let me use de default authentication already enabled to gsutil? Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, this is possible.  Go to the IAM settings for your project and you can give the Compute Engine default service account roles of your choosing (for your use case, object creator and object viewer roles only).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using signed URLs. First create a signed URL for "putting" files in GCS and then use that signed URL for copying files to GCS.

Note: Signed URLs have an expiry time limit .. set that appropriately.

More details at: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls